# File updates between open() and first read() are not read

Tags: python-3.x, file-io

External Updates that happened to that file content during the time between open() and first read() are not returned in the read() content.
How can I get the latest file content from the read()?
I've tried flush() and seek(0) but didn't help.

https://repl.it/repls/RealGreedyTransfer#main.py

```
import time

def myfoo(handle):
  print("myfoo started", flush=True)
  time.sleep(50)
  # External updates that happen during that time don't show up in read()
  # foo.flush()
  # foo.seek(0)
  # can't close and re-open file handle
  print(handle.read()) # <-- Not reading updates done after file open
  

# Upstream code base passing a file handle under an exclusive fcntl.lockf() lock
handle = open('temp.txt', 'r+')
myfoo(handle)
```

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] that demonstrates the modification of the file that your `read` doesn't pick up? The code you is not self-contained, it relies upon something outside modifying the file. And maybe it's the outside modification that isn't doing what you expect, rather than this code.

Comment: I had provided in the question the repl.it link to demonstrate the external modification of the the file. Using the provided link, manually editing the "temp.txt" file during the time.sleep() and adding any extra text reproduces the issue. The printed string only shows the contents of the file already there before the time.sleep() and doesn't show the newly added line.

Comment: I'd suspect the issue has to do with repl.it's ability to modify files while they're being used, not with the Python code itself.

Comment: @Blckknght, your comment definitely helped point in the right direction. Although, the question is answered, but if you'd like please move your comment to a post and I will up-vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the way files are written. Many text editors don’t just write to the file, they use a different method: they write to a temporary file, and then rename it to the original filename. Since renames are [atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rename_(computing)) in POSIX, in the event of a system crash during saving, the old version of the file will be available, and the new version might or might not be available in the temporary file.

For most purposes, this works as desired. The only exception is in this case, where you’re holding onto a file handle. Renames/moves/deletions do not affect the file handles, they are still open with the file they were opened with, even if that file is no longer accessible from the filesystem. You can experiment with this by opening a file, then removing it with `rm`, and then reading from the file — it will still show you the file contents from before you deleted it. You can also access the file in Linux inside `/proc/XX/fd`.

Your file handle won’t see changes, unless they are actually written (and flushed) to the same file (without the rename dance). If you’re working with something that writes by renaming, you would need to reopen the file to see the new contents.

Comment: Tried out different external editors: 
1- Used "echo UPDATED LINE >> temp.txt" and the updated line does show in python's read ().
2- Used "vim" to add the new line, and the new line does NOT show in python's read().
3- Updated ~/,vimrc with "set backupcopy=yes" to write directly to the file rather than a tmp and then "mv tmp originalfile",http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'backupcopy'  and retried vim, and now it behaves like echo, and updates are observed by python's read.
Thus, how the external writer opens and writes to the file makes a difference as mentioned.